# Search in SQL table

Tags: sql, search

Good morning,
i want to do a search in my table :
if the key search is founded then it show the result for this paramater.
else it show all the table.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to run your requirement from another client then stored procedure approach would be beneficial.

If you are trying to view your data on SQL server management studio itself then you can also consider ::

```
    DECLARE 

    @searchParam Datatype

    BEGIN

    SET @searchParam ='Value to be searched'

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE [SEARCHPARAM]=@searchParam)

    SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE [SEARCHPARAM]=@searchParam

    ELSE

    SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]

    END

    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a stored procedure as follows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [NAME]
(
    @SearchParam Datatype)
AS

BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE [SEARCHPARAM]=@SearchParam)

    SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME] WHERE [SEARCHPARAM]=@SearchParam
ELSE

SELECT * FROM [TABLENAME]

END
```

The following statement can be used to check the procedure

```
EXEC TEST_123 'VALUE'
```